# Error trying to make KNN Classifier model in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, classification, knn

I am running Knn algorithm in R studio. The packages that I am using is class:

- Version is 3.0.2 in Rstudio.
- Number of Tuples :50000
- Number of attributes : 8

The dataframe is `Final_Data` and training and testing data frames are `Train1` and `Test1`.

I am getting the error as:

```
Error in if (inherits(X[[j]], "data.frame") && ncol(xj) > 1L) X[[j]] <- as.matrix(X[[j]]) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I have cleared all the missing values .

Pls help me out in resolving this issue .

```
knn(Train1, Test1, "DepTime", k = 1, l = 0, prob = FALSE, use.all = FALSE).
```

The above knn function is the code that I am running and **DepTime** is class label.

Comment: You need to make your question [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059). At least, provide the full error message.